# Passing data directly to client

Tags: php, zend-framework

I was wondering if there was a way to pass data (an image more specifically) directly to a client without storing the image data on the server disk and/or memory using the PHP Zend Framework?

I'm currently doing this:

```
$data = "raw image data";
$type = "image/jpeg";

$response = $this->getResponse();

$response->setHeader('Content-Type', $type, true);
$response->setHeader('Content-Length', strlen($data), true);
$response->setHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary', true);
$response->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'max-age=3600, must-revalidate', true);
$response->setBody($data);

$response->sendResponse();
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are missing is `$response->sendResponse();` at the end before `exit;` and you're good.

Comment: Oh, yeah I actually had that in my code. Sorry. My question still stands. Unless, of course, I'm currently passing the data to the client directly without touching the file system or cache on the server.

Comment: Looks to me like you're already doing what you want to do. I used your code locally, and served up a JPEG image directly to my browser (that you could put in an <img> tag), which is what it sounds like you want. And you aren't writing to disk. Am I missing something?

Comment: Well I'm almost 100% sure my code will download the image data to memory on the server and then pass it to the client. What I'm trying to avoid is the hit to the server memory. I know I said file system and cache, I meant to say memory (I'll fix my question). I hope this clears this up.

Comment: Oh, that does change things. Where is the image data coming from then, if not the server? You have a remote image URL, and you're trying to pass that through to the client without the client knowing the remote image URL?

Comment: It's from another cloud serve api. Currently, this api doesn't have the functionality to serve a public link to the image. It only has the ability to serve the raw data image.

Comment: If the api can't publicly serve up the image, then you _have_ to pull the image data into memory first and send it to the client. There's no other way. You can avoid saving to the filesystem (like you're already doing) but you can't "send" data to the client without having it first.